# ¿Cómo puedo crear un bat para que haga un ping infinito?

Tags: batch

Hola estoy intentando hacer un simple lo que necesito haga ping infinito a mi  router porque muchas veces pierdo la conexion con mi router y asi me va un poco mejor.
no se mucho sobre bat pero lo que necesito es poner este comando en un bat:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -t
```

¿como podría hacerlo? y disculpar por mi ignorancia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes copia lo siguiente:

```
@echo off
title Infinite ping
echo Ctrl+c para detener la ejecución...

ping 192.168.3.29 -t
pause
```

y luego lo guardas como ping_infinito.bat o el nombre que tu quieras, solo asegurate que la extensión sea .bat

Comment: gracias y un gran saludo!

Comment: Disculpa la pregunta eso para que sirve?

Answer (score 0):

Hola quisas este te paresca mejor

```
::oculta el codigo
@echo off
::coloca el titulo
title Infinito ping bucleado
::vuelve a ejecutar el ping
inicia:
::limpia la consola
cls
::realiza el ping
ping 192.168.3.29
::vuelve a la etiqueta inicia volviendo a hacer una y otra ves la tarea sin cerrarse
goto inicia
```

Comment: Debes explicar el código, ya que habrá usuarios que no lo entiendan si no hay una explicación de por medio.

Comment: Editado amigo gracias

Answer (score 0):

Sé que la respuesta es un poco tarde pero creo que una sola línea de codigo es mejor.

```
@%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -t 192.168.1.1
```

Lo que hace es ejecutar ping.exe, el cual se encuentra en los archivos de Windows.